# Qt Java - Get image from gallery

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I am trying to get an image from `Android` gallery using Qt. I have already called the `intent` from Java using a `Java file`, but I don't know how to return it to Qt.

I have a Qt class that calls a method from a Java file that opens the `Android Image Picker`. How can I return the selected image or the selected URI to Qt?

the .h file

```
#ifndef CAMINHOIMAGENS_H
#define CAMINHOIMAGENS_H

#include <QObject>    
#include <QDebug>

class caminhoImagens : public QObject 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString imagemCaminho READ imagemCaminho NOTIFY imagemCaminhoChanged)

    slots: void atualizaImagem();
    public: QString imagemCaminho();
    private: QString m_imagemCaminho = "";
    signals: void imagemCaminhoChanged();
};

#endif // CAMINHOIMAGENS_H
```

The .cpp file

```
#include "caminhoimagens.h"    
#include <QtAndroidExtras>

caminhoImagens::caminhoImagens()
{

}

void caminhoImagens::atualizaImagem()
{
    //org.qtproject.example.acessargaleriatest
    QAndroidJniObject intent = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod ( "org/qtproject/example/AcessarGaleriaTest/ImagePickerAndroid", "imagePicker", "()Landroid/content/Intent;");
    QtAndroid::startActivity(intent, 192837465, 0);
}

QString caminhoImagens::imagemCaminho()
{
    return m_imagemCaminho;
}
```

The .java file

```
package org.qtproject.example.AcessarGaleriaTest;

import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ImagePickerAndroid extends QtActivity {
    public static Intent imagePicker() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        i.setType( "image/*");
        return Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Image");
    }
}
```

Comment: No direct solution, but a hint: You need to show new new activity for a result, and once it is finished you can get the result. See http://javatechig.com/android/writing-image-picker-using-intent-in-android

Comment: How could I do that with Qt? I mean get the results as `protected void onActivityResult` as in the link.

Comment: Well, thats where it's getting complex. Check the answere I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I have done my code in Qt using `QAndroidJniObject` to write a equivalent java code.

Register the `caminhoimages.h` as a `QML type` in the `main.cpp` and call the method `buscaImagem()`

caminhoimagens.h

```
#ifndef CAMINHOIMAGENS_H
#define CAMINHOIMAGENS_H

#include <QObject>

#include "imagepickerandroid.h"

#include <QDebug>

class caminhoImagens : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString imagemCaminho READ imagemCaminho NOTIFY imagemCaminhoChanged)

public slots:
    void buscaImagem();
    void retornaImagem(QString path);

public:
    caminhoImagens();

    QString imagemCaminho();

private:
    QString m_imagemCaminho = "";

signals:
    void imagemCaminhoChanged();
};

#endif //CAMINHOIMAGENS_H
```

caminhoimagens.cpp

```
#include "caminhoimagens.h"

caminhoImagens::caminhoImagens()
{

}

void caminhoImagens::buscaImagem()
{
    imagePickerAndroid *imagePicker = new imagePickerAndroid();
    connect(imagePicker, SIGNAL(imagemCaminhoSignal(QString)), this, SLOT(retornaImagem(QString)));

    imagePicker->buscaImagem();
}

void caminhoImagens::retornaImagem(QString path)
{
    qDebug() << path;

    m_imagemCaminho = path;

    emit imagemCaminhoChanged();
}

QString caminhoImagens::imagemCaminho()
{
    return m_imagemCaminho;
}
```

imagepickerandroid.h

```
#ifndef IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H
#define IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H


#include <QObject>
#include <QtAndroidExtras>

#include <QDebug>

class imagePickerAndroid : public QObject, public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    imagePickerAndroid();

    void buscaImagem();

    virtual void handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject & data);

signals:
    void imagemCaminhoSignal(QString);
};

#endif // IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H
```

imagepickerandroid.cpp

```
#include "imagepickerandroid.h"

imagePickerAndroid::imagePickerAndroid()
{

}

void imagePickerAndroid::buscaImagem()
{
    QAndroidJniObject ACTION_PICK = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent");
    if (ACTION_PICK.isValid() && intent.isValid())
    {
        intent.callObjectMethod("setAction", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", ACTION_PICK.object<jstring>());
        intent.callObjectMethod("setType", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QAndroidJniObject::fromString("image/*").object<jstring>());
        QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 101, this);
        qDebug() << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERRO";
    }
}

void imagePickerAndroid::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)
{
    qDebug() << "Trabalha com os dados";

    jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
    if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        QString imagemCaminho = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;").callObjectMethod("getPath", "()Ljava/lang/String;").toString();
        emit imagemCaminhoSignal(imagemCaminho);

        qDebug() << imagemCaminho;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Caminho errado";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I want to use your method but I can't use this in QML, May you, please add main.cpp and sample Qml file?

Answer (score 1):

Combining Java and C++ is a rather complex thing, at least if it's new to you. This link below shows an example on how to call Java from C++ and the other way around.

https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/BogdanVatra_Extending_Qt_Android_Apps_with_JNI.pdf

Once you know how that works in general, you can solve your problem by following this example:

http://javatechig.com/android/writing-image-picker-using-intent-in-android

To pass your uri to Qt, create a function in C++ that will be called from Java and pass the uri as a parameter.